# How can I improve theunderstanding the tone of a passage?

Tags: american-english

I'm taking preparation for GRE. For words I do like wikitionary most, because it is full of all type of contents and really very reliable. And also has all types of explanations and categories.

But to improve my understanding the tone of a passage what should I follow. I do need to follow a single site, which is much reliable like wikitionary and full of all types of details exactly like it. If anybody knows about any site then please share it. I'm badly in need for it.

Comment: _But to improve my understanding .. I do need to follow a single site_ I disagree! I often use three or four sites when learning more about a word or passage. It's hard for one dictionary to accurately capture all the nuances of a word; in this area, I would **not** recommend confining your research to a single site.

Comment: hmm, I won't disagree with you, actually I wanted to keep things simplified, but found that its not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean how to get better and pronunciation and accent? If that's what you mean, then the best way is by constantly being surrounded by people who have the accent you're trying to copy. Unfortunately, that's not always an option.

Since you tagged this with "American accent" I'm assuming you want to learn how to speak English with an American accent. You could try watching American TV, or listening to an audio book narrated by a us speaker. And if you ever have a problem with a *specific* word or phrase, feel free to post a question here.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. But I meant about authors tone for a reading passage. To understand the big picture of a passage.